# npm script is unable to find file in workdir in a docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, npm-scripts

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

This is the npm script in my package.json

```
"start": "main.js $npm_config_e $npm_config_t"
```

when I run the docker image I get this error

```
sh: 1: main.js: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! image1@1.0.0 start: `main.js`
```

However when I do an 'ls' the main.js is in the working directory (/app)
also if I change the Dockerfile to:

```
CMD ["node", "main.js"]
```

it works. So why does the npm script not find the main.js file?

Comment: How are you running the container?  Is the `main.js` file executable with a `#!` interpreter line at the start?  In your second invocation when you claim it works, what output do you actually get?  (Single quotes in JSON-format `CMD` aren't allowed and are a common cause of an obscure shell error at startup time.)

Comment: I have not added `#!` at the start of main.js, is this required for running an npm script in docker? Using `CMD ["node", "main.js"]` (the single quotes were a typo sorry) I get my expected output from Main.js. again without `#!` Thanks

Comment: If you want to directly run a script `./main.js`, it either needs to be a native executable or begin with the `#!` marker.  (Not Docker-specific.)

Comment: Sadly this didn't make a difference. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems obvious now but the solution was to add **node** to the npm script:

```
"start": "node main.js $npm_config_e $npm_config_t"
```